# How do I create reports in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Im creating an application un Symfony2.7 and I want to start creating reports, I have been reading for a couple of days and cant find a solution.
Ive tried ps pdfbundle, but I cant generate reports. Cant find more Documentation.
Please help

My Code:

```
    public function formatoOcAction($id)

{
    $facade = $this->get('ps_pdf.facade');

    $response = new Response();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $InOc = $em->getRepository('NivalInventarioBundle:InOrdenCompra')->findById($id);

    $InOcDet = $em->getRepository('NivalInventarioBundle:InOrdenCompraDetalle')->findBy(array(
        'idOrdenCompra' => $id));

    $stylesheetXml = $this->renderView('NivalInventarioBundle:InOrdenCompra:ordencompra.xml.twig', array());


    $this->render('NivalInventarioBundle:InOrdenCompra:ordencompra.pdf.twig', array(
        "entities1" => $InOc,
        "entities2" => $InOcDet,
        "id" => $id),
        $response);

    $xml = $response->getContent();

    $content = $facade->render($xml, $stylesheetXml);

    $filename = $this->getParameter('upload_directory').'orden_compra_'.$id.'.pdf';

    file_put_contents($filename, $content);

    return new Response($content, 200, array('content-type' => 'application/pdf'));
}
```

Where $id is the Id of the purchase order.

This renders a xml file to PDF but without sylesheet.

This is the twig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf SYSTEM "%resources%/dtd/doctype.dtd">
{% set empresa = app.session.get('empresa') %}

<pdf>
    <page>
<div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3>{{ empresa }}</h3>
                </td>
                <td id="s1">
                    <h2>Número: <b>{{ id }}</b></h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <h3>Orden de compra</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    Departamento de Finanzas
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        {% for entity1 in entities1 %}
            Fecha: {{ entity1.fecha|date('d-m-Y') }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="60%">Producto</td>
                        <td width="20%">Unidad</td>
                        <td>Cantidad</td>
                        <td>Precio</td>
                        <td>Total</td>
                    </tr>
                        {% set gran_total = 0 %}
                    {% for entity2 in entities2 %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ entity2.productoOc.nombre }}</td>
                            <td>{{ entity2.productoOc.unidadMedida.nombre }}</td>
                            <td class="text-right">{{ entity2.cantidad }}</td>
                            <td class="text-right">{{ entity2.precioCompra }}</td>
                            <td class="text-right">{{ entity2.total }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% set gran_total = gran_total + entity2.total %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <tr>
                        <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                        <td class="text-right" >{{ gran_total|number_format(2) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </page>
</pdf>
```

Comment: In what format your generating your report please elaborate. Do you want to apply date range filter and generate your report only with data representing in column wise or dange range with data and pictorial representation of the data with different types of chart. If you want to represent the report in any pictorial representation then please use some open source libraries like [Flot Js](http://www.flotcharts.org/), [D3 Js](https://d3js.org/) , [Chartist Js](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use: WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle, it's a bundle to facilitate using TCPDF for PDF generation in Symfony2 applications, great to make the reports we need. Please go to: https://github.com/whiteoctober/WhiteOctoberTCPDFBundle

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look at the KnpSnappyBundle which allow you to generate PDF file from many sources, including twig templates : http://knpbundles.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle

Comment: This bundle works well. Sometimes it takes time to configure the needed server binaries but is worthy.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options to choose from. I found easiest to work with:

1. [Github KnpLabs/snappy](https://github.com/mbence/OpenTBSBundle) as mentioned by *Cyrille Hejl*

   - PDF creator from html content, but in your report controller you would have to do all the work of creating:

     - header html from twig template
     - footer html from twig template
     - cover page html from twig template
     - toc XML from twig template
     - base document html from twig template
     - adding all mentioned html docs to object $pdf = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
     - PROS:

       - easy to work with Twig html
       - no memory exhaust if entity object with relations is supplied to Twig (on longer documents)
     - CONS:

       - have to supply html files from Twig template for each joined page (cover, toc, header, footer, base doc)
       - needed tinkering with right wkhtmltopdf binary version
2. [Github mbence/OpenTBSBundle](https://github.com/mbence/OpenTBSBundle)

   - This is template merger. In your report controller you will have to supply office template and all the variables, that are replaced with TBS at e.g. word template:

     - it supports OpenOffice and MSOffice templates
     - PROS:

       - customer supplies template, you just replace dynamic content with variables (customer takes care of document design)
     - CONS:

       - it could run to memory exhaust problems, since PHP script holds all input variables or arrays in memory.
       - harder to understand than Twig html (longer learning curve)